# How to access session from Warden/Devise after_authentication callback in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication, devise, warden

I'm trying to access the current session from Warden's [after_authenticate](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Callbacks) callback (running underneath Devise) in Rails 3.

At the top of my application controller I want to do something like:

```
Warden::Manager.after_authentication do |user,auth,opts|
  user.associate_with_ids(session[:pending_ids])
end
```

The ultimate goal is to take a list of record IDs that were stored in the session before sign up and associate them with the user model after sign in.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

"***auth.session***" get/sets the data in the session key "***warden.user.#{scope}.session***".

Supposing you had saved pending_ids within your rails app:

```
session[:pending_ids] = ...
```

and you wanted to acces in the warden hook, you could access it this way:

```
Warden::Manager.after_authentication do |user,auth,opts|
  user.associate_with_ids(auth.env['rack.session'][:pending_ids])
end
```

It took me a while to find that out, so I guess it might be of some help for somebody.

<sup>(originally taken from diegoscataglini.com/2012/02/09/383/manipulating-sessions-in-wardendevise, which is now dead).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can access the session store via `auth`:

```
Warden::Manager.after_authentication do |user,auth,opts|
  user.associate_with_ids(auth.session[:pending_ids])
end
```

Comment: I found that auth.session did not work.  It exists, but is not the same as session from the controller context.

Comment: When i do that i get undefined local variable or method `session' for #<Class:0x007fa2cbfe6c60>

Answer (score 1):

You can also access the session through `auth.request.session`.

So your example would be:

```
Warden::Manager.after_authentication do |user,auth,opts|
  user.associate_with_ids(auth.request.session[:pending_ids])
end
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also find the whole session from the `auth.raw_session`